# subwoofer sound preferences problem

Tags: sound

I'm having a problem with my Ubuntu and my subwoofer. It won't work until I go into sound preferences -> output tab and re-select the device. Two devices are displayed:
1: Internal Audio analog surround 5.1 (this is the one I have to use) 2: HDA NVidia Digital Stera (HDMI)

The problem is that this isn't something I have to do just once after boot. No, I have to do this everytime I want to listen to anything. IE: Whenever Rythmbox changes songs, the new song will not play through the subwoofer. I have to change the prefence on every single song. OR, whenever I watch a video, or open youtube, or do anything.
And it's not really just the subwoofer.  It's bass in general.

Basically, I can't even listen to music anymore because I always always always always have to re-set the sound preference on every song.

Now, I never had a problem before until I added a bluetooth adapter (dongle?) to my computer. After the drivers installed for that, my sound preferences won't work.

Why won't it just always work?

Please help if you can. Thanks.

Comment: What is your sound card setup?

Comment: I'm using the sound on my motherboard.  A Gigabyte P55M-UD4    3 outputs to the sound system which is 5.1 speaker set.

Comment: what `lspci | grep audio` gives?

Comment: lspci | grep  Audio  00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5  Series/3400 Series  Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)  01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation Device 0e09 (rev a1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just a guess, but in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` set `enable-lfe-remixing: no` to `yes` and make sure it is not commented (has no semicolon in front of it). If you made changes, save them and restart your system (or just pulseaudio).

Comment: That was a very good guess then.  I un-commented the line and changed it to yes and it worked.  Thank you very much.  Cheers

Comment: Glad it worked. How about an upvote and marking the question as answered?

Comment: < embarrassed >  I can't seem to figure out how to mark it as answered.  <later> Oh, think I got it but I'm not a member so can't upvote.