# Audio on MacBook 2,1

Tags: sound, macbook

How can I setup audio in Ubuntu on the Apple MacBook 2,1?

The laptop has three speakers which don't appear correctly on 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MacBook 2,1 has a 2.1 audio speakers (Left & Right speakers, and a Base).
By default the speakers are not setup properly, so the audio unbalanced. This guide will help setup a new audio profile for the speakers so the audio will sound properly.

Edit ALSA cofig file and add the new profile

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/extra-hdmi.conf
```

Find the following code in the config file

```
[Mapping analog-stereo]
device-strings = front:%f hw:%f
<omitted code>
priority = 10
```

Add the following section after the code above

```
[Mapping analog-surround-21]
device-strings = surround40:%f
channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe,lfe
paths-output = analog-output analog-output-speaker analog-output-desktop-speaker
priority = 7
direction = output
```

Restart the audio (the first part kills pulseaudio, the second reloads ALSA)

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Next you need to switch to the 2.1 audio profile, you can do this by clicking on the audio indicator in the top right, then “Sound Settings...”. In the new window look for “Mode:” setting and click on the dropdown, then click on “Analog Surround 2.1 Output”.

Comment: There is no extra-hdmi.conf in /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/ on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Any ideas how to fix audio on MacBook 2,1 running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

Also, as shown on [subwoofer sound preferences problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53802/subwoofer-sound-preferences-problem)

edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and,

find `";enable-lfe-remixing: no"` change `"no"` to `"yes"` and, uncomment (remove the ";" form the beginning of the line).

Comment: For the question asked a solution was found and worked. Adding an answer from a different question / problem seems a bit pointless. It might be an answer, but not for this question.

Comment: But it isn't fully working without the subwoofer issue resolved.  Yes it does seem to have a subwoofer channel but it is not utilized without the second fix.  The Macbooks built in sound is a lot better with both fixes implemented.