# No sound on subwoofer

Tags: sound, 15.10

I have a HP Pavilion dv7 4011eg Notebook. It has a Beats Audio 2.1 System. It uses a IDT HD Audio Codec. My problem is that I get no sound on the subwoofer. I experienced the same problem with Windows having the codec not installed, so is there a way to install it? Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Audio codecs are pre-installed and like almost all other drivers are part of the linux kernel. Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/53802/subwoofer-sound-preferences-problem?rq=1

Comment: Also, see this article: http://www.linux.org/threads/beats-audio-on-linux.4443/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it now!

I installed the program *hdajackretask* and overwrote the pin ID 0x10 with **Internal Speaker (LFE)**. Install boot override and all works fine.

Comment: Awesome, I believe you can accept your own answer as the solution to the question after 2 days to mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and then run the following command:

```
alsamixer
```

Press <kbd>F6</kbd>, use your up/down arrow keys to select your sound card and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Use your right arrow key to select the "automute" channel and use your down arrow key to toggle this to "disabled".

Now, use your right/left arrow keys to locate any channels that say **MM**.

Select any channel that says **MM** and press your <kbd>M</kbd> key to toggle **MM** to **00**.

If you see a channel for your subwoofer, adjust the volume. Use your up/down arrow keys to raise or lower the volume.

Alternatively, you can use your <kbd>W</kbd> key to raise the volume and you can use your <kbd>X</kbd> key to lower the volume.

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit `alsamixer`.

Answer (score 0):

Note: as of Ubuntu 13.10, hda-jack-retask is part of alsa-tools. Just install the alsa-tools-gui package from the regular archive and start hdajackretask.

sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui

Answer (score 0):

Also edit the following file: 
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf 
Uncommment and change the values of these lines:

enable-lfe-remixing = yes default-sample-channels = 3 default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe Second, edit the following file: sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa

Add the following line to the end:

load-module module-combine channels=3 channel_map=front-left,front-right,lfe